# Excel VBA loop and show interactively changes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA Application which loops through a range and does some changes.
However, I don't care much about the running time but I want to show the User that changes were made in run time.

I was thinking about something like this.

```
Private Sub ProcessALBODY(ByRef Fullpath, ByRef MasterWB)
...

    For Each Row In rng.rows
    ... 'Do Something

    DoEvents
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1 'for each row scrolldown and proceed to next row
    Next

...
End Sub
```

Unfortunately my application freezes until it has finished..

Comment: `ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = Row.Row`

Comment: @TimWilliams Saved my day sir, please write it as an answer!

Comment: Hey @V.Hunon what about mine?!? Aside from inducing seizures, it is awesome?!?! ☄

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = Row.Row
```

should do what you want

Comment: Nice. Better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the status bar to show progress. Use `Application.StatusBar =` and then follow it with your choice of string, integer, etc. If it is put inside the 'For' statement, it would update with each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

What select or hide not work?

```
rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    For Each row In rng.Rows

        row.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        'do something.
        rng.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Next

rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False
```

or

```
For Each row In rng.Rows

    row.Select
    'do something.

Next
```